# Minors travelling abroad alone from India

Tags: india, solo-travel, minors

As I am 15 years old I could't find age of travel abroad alone. What is the age of travel alone to abroad from india?

Comment: The question may be broader. Many countries (such as the EU) do not allow people under 16 to fly unaccompanied

Comment: This question is way too broad. Every country has its own rules, and in many you'll encounter issues when staying in a hotel or simply crossing borders. One question I found here about the topic is http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/booking-a-hotel-as-a-minor But please reduce the territory covered, at least to a continent or even a few countries. There is no possible answer to the question as it stands.

Comment: @Andrew Untrue. I've been flying unaccompanied since I was 4. Many airlines have UM programs (Unaccompanied Minor). With SAS, it is mandatory for ages 5-11, and optional for 12-15. http://www.flysas.com/en/travel-info/travel-with-children/unaccompanied-minors/

Comment: As with Nix, I've been flying from Europe to the Middle East and back since the age of 5. Until I hit my teens, a crew member would take responsibility for me during the flight. It also resulted in lots of trips to the cockpit and frequent free upgrades, but unfortunately those days are long gone now

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there isn't a law as such in India that prevents minors from travelling alone. However, each airline has their own policy on what circumstances an unaccompanied minor guest will be allowed on a flight.

Air India doesn't seem to offer too many details on its website but it [does have an unaccompanied minor service](http://www.airindia.in/SBCMS/Webpages/International---Unaccompanied-Children.aspx?MID=27), apparently. [Jet Airways is more clear on what their unaccompanied minor policy is](http://www.jetairways.com/EN/IN/ProductAndServices/UnaccompaniedMinors.aspx).

> A child between the ages of 6 years through 12 years travelling alone
>   or travelling with one or more guests who have not yet completed 18
>   years is considered an Unaccompanied Minor (UM) for international
>   travel where the entire travel is on Jet Airways.

Note that there are further exceptions in case of connecting flights, et al that have been detailed on their website along with an explanation of the protocol they follow. There is a charge levied for this service which will have to be paid.

I've mentioned the rules for the two Indian international carriers (Kingfisher no longer operates and [Indigo](http://goindigo.in/) doesn't offer any details on what their policy is). You should be able to find a similar policy page for any other airline that you're flying with.