# Can't check-in to a hotel because I am 18

Tags: usa, hotels, age-limits, syracuse

I'm 18 and traveling to the East Coast of the USA. I am staying in Syracuse, NY for 2 days, but can't seem to find a hotel that will let me check in. Are there any hotels in Syracuse with a minimum check in age of 18? I really don't want to end up homeless in Syracuse all weekend.

Comment: Related (Duplicate?): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/is-it-possible-to-book-an-hotel-being-a-minor?rq=1

Comment: No, that's different. She's a minor, I'm not.

Comment: @Ash What's the reason you're being denied?  And at which hotels.

Comment: I mentioned above, I've called to several hotels and they have a check in age of 21. My question was if anyone knows of a hotel on Syracuse with a check in age of 18.

Comment: @Ash it's not different. You're both under 21.

Comment: @KateGregory It is different as far as the law is concerned.  http://www.motel6.com/reservations/policies.aspx  There is a bit of duality in the US laws regarding this.

Comment: @Ash instead of calling, try to show up at one of them, perhaps after seeing you they will just check you in.

Comment: Not your question, but do you have someone 21 or older who could vouch for you? I.e. they book the room, even if they include some kind of deposit?

Comment: Considered a hostel? Many of them will allow 18 year olds.

Comment: It's possible to be old enough to drive a car, get married and have children but not old enough to check into a hotel. \*boggle\*

Comment: @DavidRicherby: yeah, and it's the same boggling principle here in the UK, for example Travelodge (http://www.travelodge.co.uk/terms-conditions). "You can only make a booking if you are 18 years old or over. If you arrive at the hotel and are under 18 years of age you will not be permitted to stay alone". So a 17 year old (child) 
can drive, get married and have children but can't stay in a Travelodge. Oh, and can join the army.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Along with vote, enter a legal contract, serve in the army but not drink

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Don't expect rational consistency from separately written laws. And as others have pointed out, this may be a matter of company policy rather than (or in addition to) law.

Comment: @Karlson: you may be on to something there, since the age to buy alcohol in the UK is 18. So maybe Travelodge won't let under-18-year-olds stay because they couldn't legally charge them for using the minibar ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I would wageer that you are spot on as far as the genesis of the must-be-21 rule at most hotels. If there is a mini-bar available with alcohol, they would need to empty it, or in fact may be precluded from checking in (as sole occupant) under-21 at all, ever, regardless of the current status of the bar.

Comment: @DavidRicherby et al. I 100% agree with the *boggle* comments but the "have children" part rather means "raise children", right ?

Comment: @SantiBailors That's what "have children" means, yes.

Answer (score 18):

Stay at a hostel. You shouldn't have any trouble due to your young age. You will have to buy a hostel membership, either an annual or temporary one. But the nightly fee will probably be less expensive than most hotels anyway.

There is one in Syracuse. Here's the link to check availability: 
http://www.hiusa.org/new-york/syracuse/downing-international-hostel

Comment: I have stayed in a lot of hostels and never needed to get a membership. Of course I know there are (more expensive) chains where it's necessary, but far from a requirement.

Answer (score 10):

You will need to search hotels individually for the most part and mostly away from chain hotels like [Choice Hotels](http://www.choicehotels.com), or [Wyndham](http://www.wyndham.com) and the like.

For example [Motel 6 policy](http://www.motel6.com/reservations/policies.aspx) is to allow guests of 18 years of age and older to check-in but individual hotels may deny until 19 or 21.

[Hotels.com](http://www.hotels.com) lists [Syracuse Inn & Suites](http://www.hotels.com/ho171807/syracuse-inn-suites-syracuse-united-states/).  Hilton provides [Hilton Garden Inn](http://hiltongardeninn3.hilton.com/en/hotels/new-york/hilton-garden-inn-syracuse-SYRSHGI/about/policies.html), Expedia gives [Ramada](http://www.expedia.com/Syracuse-Hotels-Ramada-Inn-Syracuse.h25930.Hotel-Information) and so on but before going there I would suggest contacting them to verify that information is actually true.

Answer (score 6):

According to Expedia.ca  (unfortunately you can't search by that parameter)

Ramada Inn Syracuse
Buckley Rd North Syracuse NY 1-855-247-4371

There may be others... apparently it's all over the place from 18 to 25 depending on the hotel.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you truly are a responsible young adult…

**Contact the hotel manager directly**, well in advance. Explain your situation. Demonstrate that you are a responsible young adult who is not going to wreck the place with a wild party or other crazy behavior. Be polite and courteous. Put yourself in the shoes of the man or woman responsible for the care and upkeep of the building and business.

Hotels don't hate young adults. They hate wild, drunk, out-of-control young adults. Unfortunately, a generation of bad parenting has made this all too common.

If you succeed in getting their approval, ask the manager to leave a note on your reservation records to avoid problems if the manager is not present when you check-in. Ask them to email you a note as well.

If you are a hooligan looking to use this approach as a scam, remember that not only can you be evicted from the room, but you can also be arrested for causing a disturbance or damaging property.