# I am 17 looking to travel within florida, what kind of places can I stay as an unaccompanied minor?

Tags: hotels, solo-travel, minors, florida

Any places I could stay safely, bed and breakfasts, inns, in daytona beach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to book an hotel being a minor?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/is-it-possible-to-book-an-hotel-being-a-minor)

Comment: You need to call a hotel, explain the situation, and they'll then make arrangements like having to pay in advance, contact information of your parents etc. etc. This is necessary, because they have to make exceptions to the usual rules barring minors to stay in a hotel, but that's simply according to the standard arrangements, minors can still stay provided the hotel is not going to be held liable for any mishaps.